# Массив не успевает обработаться

Tags: java, android, массивы, tcp-ip

Добрый день. Есть следующая проблема, сервер присылает на устройство данные размером 5125 байт. Обмен идёт по tcp/ip протоколу. Сервер сделан таким образом, что он присылает все данные фреймами, максимальный размер которых равен 2000. Таким образом размер фрейма колеблится от 5 байт до 2000 байт. Как я получаю данные:

```
   synchronized void receiveData(){
    int readCount;
       try {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[2048];
            while (din != null && (readCount = din.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            checkIncomeMsg(buffer, readCount);
            }
       }
    }
catch (IOException e){
 Log.i("LOG_TAG", "Вылетел Exception в ReceiveService");
}
}
```

Массив, счетчик и константа:

```
private static final int SHUT_DOWN_HISTORY_SIZE = 5125;
private static int shut_down_pointer = 0;
byte shutdown_history_array = new byte[5125];
```

checkIncomeMsg:

```
synchronized void checkIncomeMsg(byte[] data, int count_byte) {
        Log.i(MY_TAG, "размер входящего массива - " + count_byte);

 System.arraycopy(data, 0, shutdown_history_array, shut_down_pointer, count_byte);

 shut_down_pointer += count_byte;

  if (shut_down_pointer == SHUT_DOWN_HISTORY_SIZE){
     Log.e("LOG_TAG", "Получили весь объём данных");
  }
}
```

Так вот, вся проблема в том, что на одних устройствах весь объем данных я успешно получаю, а на других устройствах происходит ситуация, как будто приходит новый фрейм, а данные со старого фрейма еще не успели сохранится в методе `checkIncomeMsg` и он вызывается заново, таким образом я теряю часть данных.

**Вопрос:** Подскажите как решить данную проблему или посоветуйте куда копать.

**Возможное решение:** может стоит сделать какую-то очередь?

Comment: Осмелюсь предположить, что возможно происходит разрыв соединения, часть данных теряется и клиент с сервером идут в рассинхрон. Вообще выбор голого tcp/ip для мобильных клиентов мне не видится верным. Упростите протокол обмена.

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja соединение не рвётся т.к. сокет жив. Протокол изменить нет возможность, т.к. сервером является устройство с малым количеством памяти, оно передает данные по сети Wi-Fi, по протоколу tcp/ip. 
Мне кажется, что проблема именно в том, что алгоритм не успевает скопировать данные в во второй буфер, а в этот момент приходит новый фрэйм и заново вызывает метод. Такая ситуация происходит не на всех телефонах, более того один раз данные могут скачаться полностью, а во второй раз произойдет ситуация описанная выше

Comment: вы используете `byte[] buffer` - кто мешает его просто копировать в многомерный массив (а функции передавать счетчик который будет указывать положение в измерениях) и после полной загрузки уже начинать работу с данными?

Comment: Цикл не может обогнать сам себя - проблема в чём-то другом. Счётчик Ваш подозрителен - где и когда он обнуляется и зачем он в статическом поле?

Answer (score 1):

Таааак. Возможно, вам поможет такой метод класса *DataInputStream*, как `readFully(byte[] buffer)`. Он считывает байты из входного потока и записывает их в буфер *buffer*. Он блокирует выполнение программы пока не произойдет одно из следующих событий:

- *buffer.length* байт входных данных вычитаны
- обнаружен конец файла
- при возникновении какой-либо ошибки ввода / вывода.

соответственно ваш код будет выглядеть так:

```
public byte[] receiveData()
{
   try {
       byte[] buffer = new byte[SHUT_DOWN_HISTORY_SIZE];
       din.readFully(buffer);
       return buffer;
   }catch (IOException e){
       Log.i("LOG_TAG", "Вылетел Exception в ReceiveService");
       return null;
   }
}
```